# Knockout mapping with different JSON keys

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is (I believe) a simple problem with a simple question, but it has been a bit tricky to explain...

I've got knockout successfully binding to the DOM, however I'm having difficulty when it comes to updating the Javascript view models from an Ajax request.

The issue is that the names in the received JSON do not match the properties in the view models.

**View models**

```
var Group = function (data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    // Notice the Group 'name' is different to the JSON data 'title'
    this.name = ko.observable(data.title);
};

var GroupList = function (data) {
    this.groups = ko.observableArray();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        groups: {
            key: function (groupData) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(groupData.id);
            },
            create: function (options) {
                return new Group(options.data);
            }
        }
    }, this);
};
```

**Initial JSON & setup**

```
var json = {
    groups : [ {
            id : 1,
            title : 'Engineers'
        }, {
            id : 2,
            title : 'Sales'
        }
    ]
};

var viewModel = new GroupList(json);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Some time later (result of Ajax) the data is updated...**

```
var updatedJson = {
   groups : [ {
            id : 1,
            title : 'Engineers 2'
        }, {
            id : 2,
            title : 'Sales 2'
        }
    ]
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(updatedJson, {}, viewModel);
```

This JSFiddle shows the problem fully: http://jsfiddle.net/1gp3fp80/3/

When the view model is created initially it correctly "maps" the JSON `title` to the Group instance `name` property due to the line `this.name = ko.observable(data.title);`

When the view model is **updated** with `ko.mapping.fromJS(updatedJson, {}, viewModel);` the `Group` ends up with a `name` property containing the original value, and a new `title` property that has been created with the new value.

I have read the [knockout mapping documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) several times but can't figure out what to do (I'm new to modern web development).

Ultimately the question is simple: Is it possible to configure the knockout mapping plugin to map from one JSON name to a different name in the view model, and if so, how do you do it? Hopefully the answer is equally simple...

Comment: You cannot configure the mapping plugin to use a different name for the property. The whole point of the mapping plugin is to turn your models to viewmodels using matching the property names. However similarly to the custom create config you can create a custom update config where you specify that your "title" should be mapped to "name" : http://jsfiddle.net/d2m5pddm/

Comment: However in this case you are responsible to map also your other matching properties, so the whole benefit of using the mapping plugin is lost. So you should align your viewmodel to the names comming from the JSON or use the same structure for the initial and AJAX update, or don't use the mapping plugin and build your mapping logic by hand.

Comment: @nemesv thanks for your comments, they've helped a lot. I think that this situation is probably not uncommon and seems like a fairly arbitrary restriction, seems like it might be something that the framework should support. To clarify, the JSON structure is the same for the initial and AJAX updates, it's the view model that is different from the JSON. Anyway, fortunately in this case I can control both sides and will align the JSON names with the view models. Thanks again, if you want to collate those comments into an answer I'll happily accept :)

Comment: You can have two property one this.title direct and another this.name and    try using ko.pureComputed for this.name and read from this.title

Comment: Your viewModel variable contains a GroupList instance. You're trying to overwrite this variable with the data outputted by the mapping plugin. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: The call to `ko.mapping.fromJS(updatedJson, {}, viewModel)` takes the existing `viewModel` (the `GroupList` instance) and updates it with the `updatedJson`, it doesn't overwrite it.